# How to add plotly offline figure in html?

Tags: python, html, json, flask, plotly

I have created a plotly offline figure using `plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='figure_name.html')` and I would like to display it in a html page, along with text and others. How can I display it using javascript or json in flask?

Comment: `plotly.offline` is deprecated as from version 4.0 plotly is offline only. Then if you want to use you plotly generated html on a webpage you can insert it on a `iframe`

Comment: How can I insert the offline generated html in a iframe?

Comment: check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp) Please close your question cos it's a html related not a plotly question